# Android Emulator Camera Displaying Blocks

Tags: android, opencv, camera, android-emulator, emulation

I was working on the sample tutorials of OpenCV4Android. When I open the camera in my Emulator it's opening something wierd with White and black boxes.

Because of this camera, I was unable to run the sample Projects of OpenCV4Andorid.

Here's the Setup of my Emulator

[image: Emulator]

The result when I click on the camera button

[image: Camera]

Could anyone of you kindly let me know about this please. I haven't find any proper solution to my problem.

What's wrong with my camera. I configured it correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I hooked up a webcam, and under the drop-down for "Front Camera" and "Back Camera" I selected "Webcam0". Seemed to work.

What you're seeing is the 'emulated' content that just throws up something in the buffer to simulate video data.

It looks like you may be using an older version of the emulator, too. If this doesn't work, you might consider updating it.

[image]

[image]